# How to enable a disabled button jquery

Tags: jquery, click, disabled-input

I've this problem. My user can click a `-` button to subtract 1 from the total. They can't go below `0`. When I click my button to `0` and than click the `+` button to go above `0` it works. However when I want to click the `-` button again it is still disabled.

Here is my code

```
$('#minderApple').click(function(){
    $("#appletotal").val( parseInt($("#appletotal").val()) - 1);
    if ($('#appletotal').val() < 1){
        $("#minderApple").prop("disabled",true);
    }else{
        $("#minderApple").prop("disabled",false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `val()` returns a string, which you're comparing to an integer. You can convert the value to an int using `parseInt()`. Also, you can remove the `if` statement by providing the boolean value directly to `prop()`. Try this instead:

```
$('#minderApple').click(function() {
    var $appleTotal = $('#appletotal');
    var newVal = parseInt($appleTotal.val(), 10) - 1;
    $appleTotal.val(newVal);
    $(this).prop("disabled", newVal < 1);
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/kzagbe83/1/)

Comment: That's not a helpful response. What behaviour do you not get? What behaviour do you get? Any errors in the console? Seeing your HTML would also help a lot

Comment: if you click the - button ok it works. But when you put 5 in the input field and clickk the - button it doesn't work anymore

Comment: These details should have been placed in the question. To do that, you need to check the value on the `change` event of the `input` too: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/kzagbe83/2/

Comment: You are right @RoryMcCrossan, Need to provide full detail and research. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#minderApple').click(function(){
    if ((parseInt($("#appletotal").val()) - 1) < 1){
        $("#minderApple").attr("disabled","disabled");
    }else{
        $("#minderApple").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: You're still comparing string:int: `if ($('#appletotal').val() < 1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>

            .active {
                color:red;
            }
        </style>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#minderApple').click(function () {
                $("#appletotal").val(parseInt($("#appletotal").val()) - 1);
                if ($('#appletotal').val() < 1) {
                    $("#minderApple").prop("disabled", true);
                } else {
                    $("#minderApple").prop("disabled", false);
                }
            });


            $('#plus').click(function () {
                $("#appletotal").val(parseInt($("#appletotal").val()) + 1);
                if ($('#appletotal').val() >1) {
                    $("#minderApple").prop("disabled", false);
                } else {
                    $("#minderApple").prop("disabled", false);
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="appletotal" value="5"/>
      <input type="button" id="minderApple"  value="-"/>
      <input type="button" id="plus"  value="+"/>

    </body>

    </html>
```